# Login form based on user locaion

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on creating a web application in Nodejs and Express that has login forms. There are 2 types of login that can occur within the application. One is with username and password whereas the second one is with pin. Pin login is only for people who are from inside a building sharing the same wifi.

Everyone from outside the building or not connected with the wifi will have to use username and password. Right now my website uses toggle button to switch between pin login and username and password login. Here is a [link](https://codepen.io/today54/full/YzKYmJa) to my login page design in codepen.

I use Jquery to toggle between two forms

```
$(".showAdminForm").click(function(){
    $(".user-login").hide();
    $(".admin-login").show();
    $(".user-login").append('<style type="text/css">@media (max-width: 575.98px) {.login .form .signup { top: 200px;}}</style>')
})

$(".showUserForm").click(function(){
    $(".admin-login").hide();
    $(".user-login").show();
    $(".user-login").append('<style type="text/css">@media (max-width: 575.98px) {.login .form .signup { top: 150px;}}</style>')
})
```

I found this [express-ip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ip) npm module but I just wanted to know if there are any other ways to detect ip address or other solutions to my problem. Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a static IP address - the one of the *building guys*? WiFi? What if one is connected to that network by cable?

Comment: It is a static IP. Everyone will be using a tablet